# How to casting class template based on template argument type

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, casting

Currently, I store pointers of different types in a vector. To archive this, I implemented a class template "Store" which derives from a non-class template "IStore". My vector finally stores pointers to "IStore".
In code:

```
class IStore
{
public:
    IStore() = default;
    virtual ~IStore() = default;

    virtual void call() = 0;
    // ... other virtual methods
};

template<typename T>
class Store : public IStore
{
public:
    Store() = default;
    virtual ~Store() = default;

    virtual void call() override;
    // ... other virtual methods

private:
    T* m_object = nullptr;
}
```

And in my main class which holds the vector:

```
class Main
{
public:
    template<typename T>
    void registerObject(T* ptr);

    template<typename T>
    void callObjects();
    // ... other methods

private:
    std::vector<IStore*> m_storedObjects;
};
```

So far the current class structure. To describe the problem I need to introduce the following three example structs:

```
struct A {}
struct B : public A {}
struct C : {}
```

Other classes should call the Main::registerObject method with pointers to objects of A, B or C types. This method will then create a new Store<A>, Store<B> resp. Store<C> template class object and inserts this objects pointer to m_storedObjects.

Now the tricky part starts: The method Main::callObjects should be called by other classes with a template argument, such as Main::callObjects<B>(). This should iterate though m_storedObjects and call the IStore::call method for each object, which is of type B or which type B is derived from.

For example:

```
Main::registerObject<A>(obj1);
Main::registerObject<B>(obj2);
Main::registerObject<C>(obj3);
Main::callObjects<B>();
```

Should call obj1 and obj2 but not obj3, because C isn't B and B isn't derived from C.

My approaches in Main::callObjects were:
1. Perform dynamic_cast and check against nullptr like:

```
for(auto store : m_storedObjects)
{
    Store<T>* base = dynamic_cast<Store<T>*>(store);
    if(base)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

which will only work for the same classes, not derived classes, because Store<B> isn't derived from Store<A>.
2. To overwrite the cast operator in IStore and Store, such that I can specify Store should be castable when the template argument is castable. For example in Store:

```
template<typename C>
operator Store<C>*()
{
    if(std::is_convertible<T, C>::value)
    {
        return this;
    }
    else
    {
        return nullptr;
    }
}
```

But this method is never called.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?
Sorry for the long post, but I thought more code would be better to understand the problem.
Thanks for your help anyway :)

Comment: On a call to `Main::callObjects<B>()`, you want to call the method on B *or an ancestor of B*? That's interesting, as you can safely convert `B` to `A` but in general, not the other way around.

Comment: In the example above, i registered obj1, obj2 and obj3. When the user calls Main::callObjects<B>() I want to call the method IStore::call for the objects Store<A> and Store<B>. These objects are created while the user called Main::registerObject<A>() resp. Main::registerObject<B>(). The problem is, that I don't know the ancestors of B, so I can't write a simple dynamic typecast, as I already tried.

Comment: I'm running into some difficulties arising from the fact that you cannot have virtual template member functions, which would be very helpful in this situation.

Comment: A virtual template method would totally solve this, but template is compile time, virtual members are runtime components, so sadly it's not possible at all. I thought also about static members in the Store class but I think it's not possible to get the right Store template class from within IStore... 
I'm also not afraid of changing the storing mechanism at all, but I need to store different datatypes in the vector and I couldn't find any other solution to archive this...
Additionally, I'm not limited to C++11, if someone figures out a solution which requires C++14 or C++17 its alright :)

Comment: Added C++17 solution.

Answer (score 0):

After some thought, I realized that your type erasure, from assigning `Store<T>` objects to `IStore*` pointers, makes it impossible to use any compile-time type checking like `std::is_base_of` and the like. The next best option you have is run-time type information (`dynamic_cast<>()`, `typeid()`). As you observed, `dynamic_cast<>()` can't determine if an object's type is an *ancestor* of another type, only if an object's type is a descendant of another type known at compile time.

**EDIT:** With C++17 support, I can think of another way to solve your problem, based on the `std::visit` example [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit). If you change your `Main` interface...

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <variant>

template <typename T>
class Store {
public:
    using value_type = T;

    Store(T* object): m_object(object) {}

    void call() { std::cout << "Hello from " << typeid(T).name() << '\n'; }
    // ... other methods

private:
    T* m_object = nullptr;
};



template <typename... Ts>
class Main {
private:
    std::vector<std::variant<Store<Ts>...>> m_storedObjects;

public:
    // replacement for registerObjects, if you can take all objects in at once
    Main(Ts*... args): m_storedObjects({std::variant<Store<Ts>...>(Store<Ts>{args})...}) {}

    template <typename U>
    void callObjects() {
        for (auto& variant : m_storedObjects) {
            std::visit([](auto&& arg) {
                using T = typename std::decay_t<decltype(arg)>::value_type;
                if constexpr (std::is_base_of<T, U>::value) {
                    arg.call();
                }
            }, variant);
        } 
    }

};


struct A {};
struct B : public A {};
struct C {};

int main() {
    A a;
    B b;
    C c;
    auto m = Main{&a, &b, &c};
    m.callObjects<B>();
    // > Hello from 1A
    // > Hello from 1B
    return 0; 
}
```